# Axes of an ellipse generated by inclined disk

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, 3d

Suppose a disk in 3D space. Suppose that you are at the origin, and the line connecting you and the center of the ellipse generates an angle of $\theta$ with the normal to the disk. It is clear that the disk will appear as an ellipse. I have a physics textbook that states that the ratio between the axes of the apparent ellipse is
$$
\frac{b}{a} = \cos\theta
$$

How is this derived?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Any plane section of a circular cone is an ellipse, even if it is an oblique cone.The ellipse semimajor axis is however larger than disk radius, see my edited answer.

Comment: @Aretino: Of course. However, I thought that the perspective projection would distort the ellipse. I had to check it; see [this SVG image](http://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/oblique-disk.svg) of a 3D projection of an oblique disk. The "spokes" are also correctly projected to half the disk radius. The filled in area is a best-fit ellipse. Indeed, you're right: perspective projection of a circular disk does produce an ellipse, and not a distorted shape! Live and learn; thanks :)

Comment: This relation doesn't hold unless you are at infinity, not at the origin. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

That relation is only approximate. Diagram below represents a section $AB$ of a disk of radius $a$ (blue) along the plane formed by the line connecting $O$ with the center $M$ of the disk and the normal $ME$ to the disk. The orange segment $CD$ (perpendicular to $OM$) is the ellipse minor axis: if $O$ is very far from $M$ (that is $OM\gg a$) then the dotted rays can be considered approximately parallel between them (and with $OM$), the angles formed by $CD$ with the dotted rays are approximately right and each half-segment measures $b\approx a\cos\theta$.

[image]

To get the exact relation, notice that $CM:AH=OM:OH$, thus:
$$
b_1=a\cos\theta{d\over d-a\sin\theta}
\quad\hbox{and in the same way:}\quad
b_2=a\cos\theta{d\over d+a\sin\theta},
$$
where we set $d=OM$.
As $b_1+b_2=2b$, by adding the above equalities we obtain:
$$
b=a\cos\theta{d^2\over d^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}.
$$

EDIT.

It is worth mentioning that even the ellipse semimajor axis is not exactly $a$, because $a$ is the ellipse width at point $M$, which is not the midpoint of $CD$. The distance between $M$ and $CD$ midpoint is in fact
$$
b_1-b={a^2d\sin\theta\cos\theta\over d^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}.
$$
If $a'$ is the ellipse semimajor axis we must have then 
$a^2/a'^2+(b_1-b)^2/b^2=1$, whence:
$$
a'={a\over\sqrt{1-(a/d)^2\sin^2\theta}}.
$$

EDIT 2.

Let me point out that the apparent shape is always exactly an ellipse. That happens because the apparent curve is the intersection between the circular cone projected by $O$ and a plane. The center of the ellipse, as I noticed above, is not however the projection of the disk center.

Comment: I used GeoGebra, it's free. See at http://www.geogebra.org.

Comment: So the relation is correct only if the inclination angle is sufficiently small? The inclination angle is independent of the distance

Comment: The relation is correct if the ratio $a/d$ is small, for any value of $\theta$. To see that, rewrite the last relation as $$b={a\cos\theta\over1-(a/d)^2\sin^2\theta}.$$

Comment: Nice answer. It might be good to point out that the projected center of the ellipse is not at the projected center of the disk, either, in the edited part; see [here](http://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/oblique-disk.svg) for my extreme example.